# How to make an image mobile friendly?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am building a website for someone and somehow I can't manage to make the image in the header stay where it's supposed to. I am using the `@mobile` to determine the screen width, but it works only on my computer's screen. When I move to another computer, it's always to the left or to the bottom.

Code:

```css
@media (min-width: 1203px) {
  #profile {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -35.5%;
    margin-left: -31%;
    float: left; 
    padding-left: 12%
  }
  #mishpat {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1203px) {
  #profile {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -40.4%;
    margin-left: -35%;
    padding-left: 16%;
    padding-top: 6%; 
    float: left;
  }
  #mishpat {
    padding-top: 150px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 1025px) {
  #profile {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 3.5%;
    margin-left: 10%;
    padding-left: 16%;
    padding-top: 0px;
    float: left;
  }
  #mishpat {
    padding-top: 150px;
    padding-left: 0px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  #profile {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 1%;
    margin-left: 8%;
    float: left;
    bottom: 46px;
    margin-bottom: -150px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 767px) {
  #profile {
    position: relative; 
    margin-top: 2%;
    margin-left: -15%; 
    float: left; 
    bottom: 46.5px;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 470px) {
  #profile {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 18%;
    margin-left: -8%;
    float: left;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 25%;
  }
}
```

```html
 <header class="masthead text-center text-white d-flex">
          <div class="layer">
          </div>
          <div class="container my-auto">
              <div class="row">
                  <div id="mishpat" class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
                      <h1 class="text-uppercase">
                          <strong>ד"ר מריאנה ירון</strong>
                      </h1>
                      <hr>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-8 mx-auto">
                      <p class="text-faded mb-5">מומחית ברפואה פנימית ואנדוקרינולוגיה</p>

                  </div>
                  <div class="col-lg-10 mx-auto">
                      <img id="profile" src="C:\Users\alonbarel336\source\repos\WebSite1\yaron 2\img\portfolio\thumbnails\3.jpg" class="img-responsive" width="520" height="700">
                  </div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </header>
```

And here is an image to show how it looks like:
[image]

How can I make it stop before it crosses the blue line (flow to the next row)?

[the new look after fixing with bootstrap 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YD0l6.jpg)

Comment: use overflow: hidden; to that particular image tag in css

Comment: didn't change anything @narayanmaity

Comment: Try this property  z-index:1; to section 2 or the bluish part z-index only works in positioned element (absolute, fixed , relative) try this also give z-index:0 to that image;

Answer (score 0):

To make the image responsive do this:

1. Replace `img-responsive` with `img-fluid`. (there's no `img-responsive` in Bootstrap 4)
2. Remove `width="520" height="700"`.

Comment: can you explain what "Remove all of your custom css and replace it with native Bootstrap 4 classes" means? like which classes, how do i find those classes on the internet so i can understand what I'm doing?

Comment: Remove `float:left` and replace your margin and padding rules with Bootstrap 4 spacing classes: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

Comment: I removed the last point because that isn't really necessary to make the image "mobile-friendly". But there are other things that are wrong with your code. However, since you haven't posted a [mcve], my answer answers the question in regards to making an image responsive in general.

Comment: do you mean you want to see the whole html and css code

Comment: ok I did what you said, and the image is responsive to the left (it sticks to where it should be at the left side and away from the text.) but the horizontal line is staying as it is, so when i change the size of the window it looks like this (edited post) , so now the only problem i have is that i want the picture to stick to the blue line. thanks for the help

Comment: No, you haven't done what I said. You just dumped the code for the entire page here. Also, there is NO "blue line" anywhere. Read the following page **5 times from start to finish** and do what it says there: [mcve]